# Assistance with an associate method call

Tags: c#

Below I have this code I've been working on for an exercise, not assignment work, its to incorporate association. In the main I have C2.buyPhoneApple(P1); this calls the method within my Customer class. Back to my main, I have a list, this list is made up of items added to the phone class, my problem is, I used P1 to test the call, it works, but now I need the method call to reflect the item within the list and take 1 from the stock once the order is placed. I've tried to explain this as best as possible.

In addition to this, I use a variable called model to store the users selection from the iterated list(0, 1, 2) I use that variable to confirm the users choice by indexing the applePhones library, excuse the lengthy explanation.

P.S. I do have more code, but didn't feel the need to post all the classes.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace OOP_Phone_Shop_Test
{
    class Program
    {

        static int thanksApple(ref int thankYou)
        {
            Random text = new Random();
            thankYou = text.Next(1, 4);

            switch (thankYou)
            {
                case 1:
                    Console.WriteLine("\nThank you for choosing Apple!\n");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Console.WriteLine("\nCongratualation on purchasing your Apple product!\n");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Console.WriteLine("\nWelcome to Apple, you shall receieve your account information and billing through the mail.\n");
                    break;
                case 4:
                    Console.WriteLine("\nCell-Sale, number 1 for Apple products and services!\n");
                    break;
            }

            return thankYou;
        }
        static void menu()
        {


        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            menu();
            int model = 0;
            bool menuRepeat = true;
            string confirm = "";
            int choice = 0;

            do
            {
                AppleLibrary appleLib = new AppleLibrary();
                SamsungLibrary samsungLib = new SamsungLibrary();
                Customer C1 = new Customer("Poseidon", 500, 309487, "The Sea, Greece"); //Instantiation with predefined values due to predefined constructor.
                Customer C2 = new Customer("Zeus", 601, 345928, "Olympus, Greece");
                Windows W1 = new Windows(); 



                W1.brand = "Windows"; 
                W1.model = "Nokia Lumia";
                W1.stock = 5;

                Samsung Sam2 = new Samsung(); 
                Sam2.brand = "Samsung, Andriod";
                Sam2.Model = "Samsung Galaxy note 3";
                Sam2.stock = 5;
                Sam2.price = 300;

                Apple P1 = new Apple();
                P1.brand = "Apple";
                P1.model = "iPhone 5";
                P1.stock = 5;
                P1.price = 350;

                appleLib.ApplePhones.Add(new Phone("Apple", "iPhone 5", 350, 1));//Adding to the library object with initialization (Predefined constructor)
                appleLib.ApplePhones.Add(new Phone("Apple", "iPhone 4s", 250, 1));
                appleLib.ApplePhones.Add(new Phone("Apple", "iPhone 3", 150, 0));
                samsungLib.samsungPhones.Add(new Phone("Samsung", "Galaxy Note 1", 100, 7));
                samsungLib.samsungPhones.Add(new Phone("Samsung", "Galaxy Note 2", 150, 2));
                samsungLib.samsungPhones.Add(new Phone("Samsung", "Galaxy Note 3", 350, 4));

                Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGreen;
                /*
                for (int j = 0; j < windowsPhoneArray.Length; j++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}", windowsPhoneArray[j].model);
                }
                 * */

                Console.WriteLine("\nCustomer name: {0}\nCustomer balance: {1}\n", C1.name, C1.balance);

                Console.WriteLine("\n1)Apple\n\n2)Samsung\n\n3)Windows\n");

                Console.Write("Please select a brand: ");

                try
                {
                    choice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                }

                catch (FormatException)
                {
                    Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGray;
                    Console.WriteLine("\n\n***Please enter a number***\n\n");
                }

                if (choice == 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nPlease Select a model");

                    for (int i = 0; i < appleLib.ApplePhones.Count(); i++)
                    {
                        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkMagenta;
                        Console.Write("\nSelection {0}) = Model: {1}\nPrice: {2}\nStock: {3}\n", i, appleLib.ApplePhones[i].model, appleLib.ApplePhones[i].price, appleLib.ApplePhones[i].stock);
                    }

                    Console.Write("\nPlease select your model: ");

                    try
                    {
                       model = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); //This variable to show/confirm the users list<phone> selection.
                    }

                    catch (FormatException)
                    {
                        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGray;
                        Console.WriteLine("\nPlease enter a number\n");
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("\nYou have selected: {0}\nPrice: {1}", appleLib.ApplePhones[model].Brand, appleLib.ApplePhones[model].price);


                    Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
                    Console.Write("\nConfirm purchase Y/N: ");
                    confirm = Console.ReadLine();

                    if (confirm == "y" || confirm == "Y")
                    {
                        menuRepeat = false;
                        C2.BuyPhoneApple(P1);// I want this call to reflect the chosen element within the list<phone> and call buyPhoneApple and remove a phone from the stock according to the users selection.
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Returning to the main menu...standby");
                    }

                }

                if (choice == 2)
                {
                    for (int x = 0; x < samsungLib.samsungPhones.Count(); x++)
                    {
                        Console.Write("\nSelection {0}) = Model: {1}\nStock: {2}\n", x, samsungLib.samsungPhones[x].model, samsungLib.samsungPhones[x].stock);
                    }

                    Console.Write("\nPlease select your model: ");

                    try
                    {
                        model = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    }
                    catch (FormatException)
                    {
                        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGray;
                        Console.WriteLine("\nPlease enter a number\n");
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("\nYou have selected: {0}\nPrice: {1}", samsungLib.samsungPhones[model].brand, samsungLib.samsungPhones[model].price);

                    Console.Write("\nConfirm purchase Y/N: ");
                    confirm = Console.ReadLine();

                    if (confirm == "y" || confirm == "Y")
                    {
                        menuRepeat = false;
                        C2.BuyPhoneApple(P1);
                    }
                }
            } while (menuRepeat == true);
        }
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace OOP_Phone_Shop_Test
{
    class Apple : Phone
    {
        public Apple(string newBrand, string newModel, int newPrice, int newStock)
            : base(newBrand, newModel, newPrice, newStock)
        {
        }
        public Apple()
        {
        }
        static int thanksApple(ref int thankYou)
        {
            Random text = new Random();
            thankYou = text.Next(1, 4);

            switch (thankYou)
            {
                case 1:
                    Console.WriteLine("\nThank you for choosing Apple!\n");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Console.WriteLine("\nCongratualation on purchasing your Apple product!\n");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Console.WriteLine("\nWelcome to Apple, you shall receieve your account information and billing through the mail.\n");
                    break;
                case 4:
                    Console.WriteLine("\nCell-Sale, number 1 for Apple products and services!\n");
                    break;
            }

            return thankYou;
        }
        public override void OrderPhoneApple(Customer objCustomer)
        {
            int thankyouApple = 0;
            stock--;
            Console.WriteLine("\n\nSold!\n\nName: {0}\nAccount Number: {1}\nAddress: {2}", objCustomer.name, objCustomer.AccountNumber, objCustomer.Address);
            thanksApple(ref thankyouApple);
        }
        public override void AddStock()
        {
            stock++;
            Console.WriteLine("Single stock added!");
        }
        public override void AddMassStock(int MassStock)
        {
            stock = stock + MassStock;
            Console.WriteLine("stock added!");
        }
        public override void RemoveStock()
        {
            stock--;
            Console.WriteLine("Single stock removed!");
        }
        public override void RemoveMassStock(int RemoveMassStock)
        {
            stock = stock - RemoveMassStock;
            Console.WriteLine("stock removed!");
        }
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace OOP_Phone_Shop_Test
{
    class Customer
    {
        public string name;
        public double balance;
        public double accountNumber;
        public string address;

        public Customer(string newName, double newBalance, double newAccountNumber, string newAddress)
        {
            name = newName;
            balance = newBalance;
            accountNumber = newAccountNumber;
            address = newAddress;
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return name;
            }
            set
            {
                name = value;
            }
        }
        public double Balance
        {
            get
            {
                return balance;
            }
            set
            {
                balance = value;
            }
        }
        public double AccountNumber
        {
            get
            {
                return accountNumber;
            }
            set
            {
                accountNumber = value;
            }
        }
        public string Address
        {
            get
            {
                return address;
            }
            set
            {
                address = value;
            }
        }
        public void BuyPhoneApple(Apple objApplePhone)
        {
            if (balance >= objApplePhone.price)
            {
                objApplePhone.OrderPhoneApple(this);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Not enouogh funds");
            }
        }
        public void BuyPhoneSamsung(Samsung objSamsungPhone)
        {
            if (balance >= objSamsungPhone.price)
            {
                objSamsungPhone.OrderPhoneSamsung(this);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Not enough funds");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you somehow breakdown your problem, instead of posting the whole code which is not relevant?

Comment: I have a class called AppleLibrary, which is a list<phone> which is comprised of the phone class objects, within the main I have C1 and C2 which are Customer objects with predefined constructor values. buyPhoneApple is a method in the Customer class, passes an object of that class to apple, which has a method, which once called, removes one of that models stock stock--; I need to somehow place the element of the list that the user selects within the associate call of C2.buyapplePhone(list element selected); so it will proceed to take one from the stock within the constructor value.

Answer (score 1):

According to your question and the code you are posted, what you are asking is that you need a way to remove the ordered phones from the apple store which for you is the AppleLibrary class and use the purchased phone down the processing chain.

First thing you need to do is to **refactor** your code and put a service method to carry out the order related services which you stuffed in the Phone model class.

secondly simplify your inheritance chain to just indicate the phone type using an enum value property.

Then simplify the customer domain method by just removing all that Buy*** methods then implement a generic Buy method that takes in a phone object and passes itself with either the phone object or model to the PhoneOrderService that you created before. This can be represented in code as shown below

```
public class Customer
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public double AccountNumber { get; set; }
        public double AvaliableBalance { get; set; }

        public void Buy(Phone phone)
        {
            if (phone == null)
                return;
            var phoneService = new PhoneOrderService();

            if (phoneService.PurchasePhone(this, phone.Model))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} phone purchased!", phone.Model);
            }
        }

namespace PhoneApp
{
    public enum PhoneType : int
    {
        Apple,
        Windows, 
        Samsung
    }


    public class Phone
    {
        public string Brand { get;  set; }
       public string Model { get;  set; }
       public double Price { get; set; }
       public int QuantityInStock { get; set; }
       public PhoneType PhoneType { get; set; }

    }
}

namespace PhoneApp
{
    public class PhoneOrderService
    {
        // I used a private static list here as a backup storeage for ease of 
        // implementation and simplicity of the example.
        private static List<Phone> _itemsInStock  = new List<Phone>();

        public void AddToStock(Phone phone)
        {
            if(phone == null)
                return;

            _itemsInStock.Add(phone);
        }

        //Now add those methods in your apple model to this service.

        public bool PurchasePhone(Customer customer, string model)
        {
            if (customer == null)
                return false;

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model))
                return false;

            var phone = _itemsInStock.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Model == model);


            if (phone != null)
            {
                if (customer.AvaliableBalance < phone.Price)
                    return false;

                customer.AvaliableBalance -= phone.Price;

                phone.QuantityInStock -= 1;    

                AddToStock(phone);
            }

            // then you use the phone to do whatever you like
            //after return true to the calling method to show that this action ucceeded.

            return true;
        }
    }
}


namespace PhoneApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //initialize the PhoneOrderService
            var phoneOrderService = new PhoneOrderService();

            //initialize the phone model
            var phone1 = new Phone
            {
                Model = "IPhone 5",
                Price = 450,
                QuantityInStock = 5,
                Brand = "Brand new",
                PhoneType = PhoneType.Apple
            };

            //initialize the phone model
            var phone2 = new Phone
            {
                Model = "Nokia Lumia",
                Price = 500,
                QuantityInStock = 3,
                Brand = "Brand new",
                PhoneType = PhoneType.Windows
            };

            //initialize the phone model
            var phone3 = new Phone
            {
                Model = "Galaxy 4 tab",
                Price = 350,
                QuantityInStock = 7,
                Brand = "Brand new",
                PhoneType = PhoneType.Samsung
            };

            //Add the phones to the phone order service
            phoneOrderService.AddToStock(phone1);
            phoneOrderService.AddToStock(phone2);
            phoneOrderService.AddToStock(phone3);


            //Initialize the customer model
            var customer = new Customer
            {
                Name = "Mr Moon",
                AvaliableBalance = 1000,
                Address = "41 new street road!",
                AccountNumber = 1234567889
            };

            customer.Buy(phone1);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please be aware that I've not used enum's before, this is only my second week of OOP, enum's haven't been taught yet.

Comment: Okay, in that case use the inheritance hierarchy that you were using. Now in the `PurchasePhone(Customer customer, Phone phone)` method of the **PhoneOrderService** class, pass an object of the phone you want to buy. Inside this method identify the type of phone in an if/else statement by checking the type of phone like this `if(phone.GetType() == typeof(Apple))` then put the logic for processing apple phone inside the apple if block. Use the same style for checking the order phones.

Comment: It was fixed by changing the type-case, instead of using list<phone> using list<Apple> and so forth, condensing the library down to one library consisting of three list class members and initializing them as objects, then, using the model variable to index and match the order and remove the matching stock.